# LINQ Grouping by

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.6

I have list of class objects similar

```
 public class MyClass
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
    }
```

I have list of this, where I want to group them by UserId. Result I am after is sets of `List<MyClass>` where each list is by user

I have applied the group by but not sure how the select should be

```
  var group = items.GroupBy(g => g.UserId).
                Select(s=> new MyClass { 
                UserId = s.Key,
              
                }).ToList();
```

Sample data

```
  var items = new List<MyClass>
            {
                new MyClass{UserId = 100, ItemId = 245, ItemName = "ABC"},
                new MyClass{UserId = 100, ItemId = 125, ItemName = "ABCff"},
                new MyClass{UserId = 150, ItemId = 233, ItemName = "AweBC"},
                new MyClass{UserId = 100, ItemId = 233, ItemName = "ABweweC"}
            };
```

Here I would expect two sets of `List<MyClass>` one list with userid 100 and other with 150 and each list will have 2 class objects

Comment: How the output should be? UserId, List<MyClass>?

Comment: No, just `List<MyClass>`

Comment: then you can Order current `items` by `UserId` so that all your records with the same UserId will be at the same group

Comment: I have updated question with sample data and expected result

Comment: You want List<List<MyClass>> ?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty: yes correct

Comment: I will also recommend a quick look at the example in the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1). Here grouping return an already grouped result `items.GroupBy(g => g.UserId).ToList()` https://dotnetfiddle.net/CmWnd8

Comment: Please [edit] your question with an example of what the outcome data structure should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after this which will give you `List<List<MyClass>>`

```
var group = items.GroupBy(g => g.UserId).Select(s => s.ToList());
```

Comment: That's IEnumerable<List<MyClass>>, right? Missing a ToList

Comment: I think you get the idea is it

Comment: exactly what i was after

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary with `UserId` as it's key:

```
var groups = items.GroupBy(c => c.UserId)
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Now for example, the following:

```
 Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, groups[100]));
```

Will print out:

```
100 245 ABC
100 125 ABCff
100 233 ABweweC
```